# Making rain particle as shadows

Tags: unity-game-engine, particles, shadows

I've created following scene:
[image]

What you see is the light shining through a window to the back wall of the room. Outside is a tree blowing in the wind. What I'm trying to simulate it a stormy weather, so I need to add rain to the scenery as well. However, I just need it as a shadow through the window. How is this done, can it simply be done through Unity's Particle System, or do I need shader etc.?

Comment: Use particle system, it has rendering module where you can play around with material/texture/shader to get the desired result. I would go for a grey/black colour to make it look like a shadow

Comment: @UmairM Ah I missed that tab, worked like a charm

Comment: I have added an answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use particle system, it has [Renderer Module](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PartSysRendererModule.html) where you can play around with material/texture/shader to get the desired result.

I would go for a grey/black colour to make it look like a shadow

[image]

Comment: Seems like you missed the image link @UmairM

Comment: Sorry, Didn't get what you are trying to say?

Comment: I see at the bottom line "enter image description here" but there is no link attached to it ?

Comment: I can see the image in answer. However it is not clickable. Are you talking about edit mode?

Comment: Yes that was not clickable, now you removed it i assume. Not a big deal, was just a heads up.